# How to hide the actionbar ? (Sherlock Implementation)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a typical case where I have used SherlockActionBar for horizontal scrolling. I want the title bar**(one where it depicts the android default icon and app name)** in my activity to disappear. To be more clear, I do not want the bar that is present at the top of the screen but I use a action bar next to it for navigation which is vital. How do I make the top one disappear ? Any ideas will be highly appreciated. An example image is given below :

[image]

I hope the question is clear. Feel free to ask for more.

Answer (score 2):

to hide programmatically AB/ABS you can use

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: But when I use that I tend to find that the actionbar i.e; the one which is used for navigation also to disappear !!

Comment: I did not get it. Could you rephrase  it?

Comment: Please check out my new image which will be more clear

Comment: so what happens if you hide FinalSherlock? Try with getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);              
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); instead of hide()

Comment: did you gave it a try?

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using support libraries

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

otherwise

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

**NOTE:** if your activity `extends SherlockFragmentActivity` then only the `getSupportActionBar().hide();` method will be visible otherwise you will get only `getActionBar().hide();` that works with minimum API level 11.

Comment: getActionBar() is possible from API Level 11 but I want from basic API Level. Any other alternatives ?

Comment: are you using ABS(ActionBarSharlok) library?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Action bar (API Level>11)

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

or if you are using actionbar sherelock lib (API Level <11)

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Credits goes to blackbelt(answer was delvered via comments) :

**getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);**

Calling these functions would remove the title bar. This removed my title bar but the action bar was safe and sound. Thanks to blackbelt.